# how to provide copy of options lists for multiple mat-select dropdown using mat-select-filter in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I'm using mat-select in a table which is generating numbers of dropdowns dynamically base on different criteria. after adding mat-select-filter for the dropdown for user to search from the list when I search in one dropdown all the other dropdowns are getting update.  I figure out that because I'm referencing to same array, I need solution to get a copy for each dropdown.
component.ts

```
   public variables = ['One','Two','County', 'Three', 'Zebra', 'XiOn'];
    public filteredList1 = this.variables.slice();
```

component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Basic">
        <mat-select-filter [array]="variables" (filteredReturn)="filteredList1 =$event"></mat-select-filter>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredList1" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Basic">
        <mat-select-filter [array]="variables" (filteredReturn)="filteredList1 =$event"></mat-select-filter>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredList1" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

filteredList1  is the one I'm referring in both dropdowns, since number of dropdowns are vary I can't use multiple filteredList1,
Looking for a quick reply from experts.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Method 1: Create a method and use map on your array.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Basic">
        <mat-select-filter [array]="variables" (filteredReturn)="filteredList1 =$event"></mat-select-filter>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of getFilters()" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
public variables = ['One','Two','County', 'Three', 'Zebra', 'XiOn'];
public filteredList1 = this.variables.slice();

public getFilters() {
    return this.filteredList1.map(_ => _);
}
```

2. Method 2: User slice pipe provided by angular.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Basic">
        <mat-select-filter [array]="variables" (filteredReturn)="filteredList1 =$event"></mat-select-filter>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredList1 | slice : 0" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```